# MediaBrowser(Compat) subscribe/query items with pagination

Tags: android, pagination, android-support-library

In my Service-side, it has huge data and I want to provide items with pagination way.
Is there any recommended flow to traverse with pagination between MediaBrowser/MediaBrowserService(Compat)?

I want to provide partial data in `Result<List<MediaItem>>` instead of all data (e.g. all YouTube songs), while browser-side using pagination to pull partial data once a time.

Answer (score 2):

In your

```
MediaService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat

  @Override
    public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull final String parentMediaId, @NonNull final Result<List<MediaItem>> result) {
       result.detach();
       for (int page = 0; i<pages.size(); i++){
            result.sendResult(getList(page));
         }
    }
public List<MediaItem> getList(int page){
  //here create List for page-number == page
}
```

OR 
You can make request in your Fragment or Activity with page

```
MediaBrowserCompat mediaBrowser = ...;
mediaBrowser.subscribe("1"/*it's page*/, mSubscriptionCallback);
```

then in your Service make this:

```
 @Override
        public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull final String page, @NonNull final Result<List<MediaItem>> result) {
           result.detach();
           result.sendResult(getList(page));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do a similar thing in my app - I wanted to return the existing songs on the device but in paginated way. Like you say, a partial result in the onLoadChildren() method. I ended up using Android's new [Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) to do just that. Using the library, I could make the client/UI side asks the service for only the pages the user is interested to see, and then serve only those in the onLoadChildren() method, calling the client's subscribe() method to retrieve it.
I go over it in details in a [post I wrote](https://medium.com/@shevach/how-to-paginate-mediabrowserservice-e4fdc902ff2), where I also give code samples to better demonstrate the concept.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20111808)

Comment: Care to explain why doesn't this answer the question? I describe how I solved a very similar problem, and even link to the post I wrote where I explain the solution in much greater detail and share code samples. I think my answer, with the linked post, can really answer the question and help the asker, as he asks about pagination, which is exactly what I faced with too.